# Trying to Access a Database in both Client and Server Components on NextJS 13

Tags: sql, reactjs, database, postgresql, next.js

I am building an app on Next.js 13. In my app I want to connect to a cloud pg database and populate the data into tables inside a server side component. This component will be creating tables with all the data displayed but I want each table cell to be interactive, so that when the value of the cells are changed, Update Queries can be made to adjust the database to replace the old values with the values entered in the cell. This table cell component would be a client component. So in summary I am trying to create a server side component, composed of client components. I want both the server component and it's child components to have access to the database so I can make queries from both files. However, when connecting both to the database I encounter a "cloudflare sockets" error. How can I make it so that both components have access to the database? Currently I have no problem connecting the server component to the database to populate the data but the error comes once I connect in the child client components. [image: Display ComponentTableCell Component]

I want to be able to access the database from both components. Not just the data itself. I want to be able to make quieries to the database itself from both files. I have tried passing down the connection as props into the TableCell, but you can't pass functions as props into client components.

Comment: I tried to pass down the URI i want to connect to as props to the TableCell component and use pg.Client(props.URI) to connect to the URI in TableCell but that is exactly what cause the "cloudflare sockets" error.